# How can I create a generic method which write a dictionary to a csv file?

Tags: c#, function

I want to write a a function that recives a dictionary with arbitrary keys and values types, and write them to a csv file. for example if i have the following class:

```
public class VerificationResult
{
    public enum resInfo
    {
        sessionID,
        testFilePath,
        testFileName,
        ID1,
        ID2,
        score1,
        score2,
        isGood,
        isTrue
    };

    public string[] resData = 
        new string[Enum.GetNames(typeof (resInfo)).Length];

    public VerificationResult(int sessionID,
                              string testFilePath,
                              string Id1,
                              string Id2,
                              string score1,
                              string score2,
                              string isGood)
    {
        resData[(int) resInfo.sessionID] = sessionID.ToString();
        resData[(int) resInfo.testFilePath] = testFilePath;
        resData[(int) resInfo.testFileName] =
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(testFilePath);
        resData[(int) resInfo.ID1] = Id1;
        resData[(int) resInfo.ID2] = Id2;
        resData[(int) resInfo.score1] = Score1;
        resData[(int) resInfo.score2] = Score2;
        resData[(int) resInfo.isGood] = isGood;
        resData[(int) resInfo.isTrue] = (Id1 == IsGood).ToString();
    }
};
```

and a dictionary defined as:

```
private Dictionary<int,VerificationResult> verificationResults
```

I would want to creat a generic function that will be able to print this dictionary to a csv file, with headers of the values members (in this case the members of the VerificationResult class.

Ive decided to send as an argument an array or the enum of the members of the value type. the problem  is I wont necesserily know what is the name of the value class member that holds the array of data i need or (if i decide to implement it differently) how to iterate through the unknown value class members and print them to a file. Is there a way to do that without using eval like functions? Am i trying to much? should I just write a specific functions each time I need to and leave it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with delegates to specify how the string representation of the Keys and Values should look like. In my example I created the method as an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for IDictionary.

```
public static class DictionaryExtension {
    public static void WriteToCsv<K, V>(
        this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary,
        string path,
        Func<K, string> keyToString,
        Func<V, string> valueToString,
        string separator) {

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<K, V> keyValuePair in dictionary)
            content.AppendLine(string.Join(separator, new List<string> {
                keyToString(keyValuePair.Key),
                valueToString(keyValuePair.Value)
            }));

        File.WriteAllText(path, content.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now given you have a complex type with arbitrary internal structure like your `VerificationResult`:

```
public class ComplexType {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<long, ComplexType> test = new Dictionary<long, ComplexType>();
test.Add(1, new ComplexType { Number = 1, Name = "one"});
test.Add(2, new ComplexType { Number = 1, Name = "two" });
test.Add(3, new ComplexType { Number = 1, Name = "three" });
test.Add(4, new ComplexType { Number = 1, Name = "four" });
```

a simple

```
test.WriteToCsv(@"C:\temp\dictionarytest.txt",
    key => key.ToString(),
    value => value.Name,
    ";");
```

is enough to write the dictionary:

```
1;one
2;two
3;three
4;four
```